# General Linear Group $GL_n(R)$ not Finitely Generated

Tags: group-theory, linear-groups

Let $R$ an ***infinite*** field (or more general an infinite ring).

Let consider for $n \ge 2$ the general linear group $GL_n(R)$ and the special linear group $SL_n(R)$ considered with canonical matrix multiplication as group operation.

How to see that $GL_n(R)$ is not finitely generated as group?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider determinants. If $F$ is an infinite field, the determinants of a generating set of $\textrm{GL}_n(F)$ must generate the multiplicative
group $F^*$. But $F^*$ contains a copy of either $\Bbb Q^*$, $\Bbb F_p(T)^*$ or is torsion but infinite, so cannot be finitely generated.

If $R$ is an infinite ring, then $\textrm{GL}_n(R)$ can be finitely
generated, for instance when $R=\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the enlightening answer. Do you have a nice reference where is proved that $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated?

Comment: Well, $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$ is generated by elementary matrices.

Answer (score 0):

They are uncountable and every finitely generated group is either finite or countable.

Comment: But what about for example $R= \mathbb{Q}$? $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so for $GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$ is also countable, or not?

Comment: @KarlPeter I thought that $R$ meant $\mathbb R$. What does it mean then? Anyway, what I wrote proves that the answer is negative when $R=\mathbb R$.

Comment: By $R$ I considered an arbitrary infinite field or a ring.