# General Linear Group $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ of Integers is finitely generated

Tags: group-theory, linear-groups

My question refers to following former question of mine: [General Linear Group $GL_n(R)$ not Finitely Generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654172/general-linear-group-gl-nr-not-finitely-generated)

I want to know how to see that the general linear group $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ of integers is finitely generated.

Comment: Well, what have you considered, before posting?  Please include your thoughts on this question, including perhaps the definition of being finitely generated, in your own words?

Comment: I know that  $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})= \{m \in  Mat_n(\mathbb{Z}) | det(m) = \pm 1 \}$ because the map $det:$GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ \to \mathbb{Z}^* \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ must as a homomorphism be compatible with multiplicative structure of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ as well as of  $\mathbb{Z}^* \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$. But I don't see how this helps to solve my problem...

Comment: This might be helpful: http://comp.uark.edu/~matthewd/679V/autZnnotes.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) algorithm shows that a matrix in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ can be diagonalized by elementary row and column operations. A row operation is the same as multiplying on the left by a power of an elementary matrix (a matrix with all $1$'s on the diagonal and a single off diagonal $1$). A column operation is the same as multiplying on the right by a power of an elementary matrix. A non-identity diagonal matrix in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is a product of special diagonal matrices having all $1$'s except for a single $-1$ on the diagonal. So $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by elementary matrices and special diagonal matrices.